# What are the different approaches to configure application.properties file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

One way is to directly edit appliaction.properties file in any editor and write the contents.
Is there any other external approach to do the same because in one of my project, I am unable to find anything in application.properties file when I open it in editor but when I run the application I get some information out of application.properties file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The properties may be configured in many different standard ways with SpringBoot. I think the best way to identify where your parameters are is to list the locations given in the [SpringBoot configuration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and check if your parameters are here.

**EDIT** List the locations :

> 1. Devtools global settings properties on your home directory (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
> 2. @TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
> 3. properties attribute on your tests. Available on @SpringBootTest and the test annotations for testing a particular slice of your application.
> 4. Command line arguments.
> 5. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> 6. ServletConfig init parameters.
> 7. ServletContext init parameters.
> 8. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
> 9. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> 10. OS environment variables.
> 11. A RandomValuePropertySource that has properties only in random.*.
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 16. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
> 17. Default properties (specified by setting SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).